# Getting an exe to work in PATH

Tags: path, git-bash, system32

I got jq to work on my local computer by adding the exe i downloaded to a specific folder. Pictured below. This is a user variable location.

[image]

I placed the exe in the C:\Users\Justin.dnx\bin location.

I now did pretty much the same thing on an AzureVM and git bash is not recognizing jq. I plecaed the jq.exe below.

[image]

I placed the exe in the C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing chocolaty and installing jq through that and it worked.